# MsDeploy skip App_Data folder from publishing

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, msdeploy

I was trying to deploy a site by skipping App_Data folder. Because of business requirement I need few files in it.

How can I skip the folder.

I have used the following commands, it didn't help me out.

msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=abc.Web.zip -dest:auto,computername="abc.local",username="abc",password="abc" -setParam:kind=ProviderPath,scope=iisApp,value="abc.com" -allowUntrusted

-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=.*App_Data.*,skipAction=delete

I have tried many Permutations and combinations.

I appreciate if someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try `-skip:Directory=App_Data` it works for me (but i don`t have nested folders in it)

You can also add `-debug -verbose` to see the output of ms deploy, it should explain reason of updating\deleting a file.

Comment: I had to mention each directory path to skip from deleting, and verbose is one I always use to get detailed command execution, thanks for mentioning.